# Report on cloudpage activity in marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, landing-page, cloudpage

I want to see a rundown of my most visited and clicked cloudpages. I can see this data one page at a time looking at activity. SFMC reports on the single top page in the overview. I know the data is there. I just can't figure out how to get it all in one place. Suggestions?

Comment: I'm also trying to find ways to display data and metrics in a unified report.  Looking at having a cloudpage that displays this